# What is causing punctuation to appear around my matrices?

Tags: plain-tex, characters, catcodes

I have an input file called `mathchar.tex`, which I rely on pretty heavily:

```
\mathchardef\Gamma="7400
\mathchardef\Delta="7401
\mathchardef\Theta="7402
\mathchardef\Lambda="7403
\mathchardef\Xi="7404
\mathchardef\Pi="7405
\mathchardef\Sigma="7406
\mathchardef\Upsilon="7407
\mathchardef\Phi="7408
\mathchardef\Psi="7409
\mathchardef\Omega="740A




%%%%%%

\mathchardef\alpha="040B
\mathchardef\beta="040C
\mathchardef\gamma="040D
\mathchardef\delta="040E
\mathchardef\epsilon="040F
\mathchardef\zeta="0410
\mathchardef\eta="0411
\mathchardef\theta="0412
\mathchardef\iota="0413
\mathchardef\kappa="0414
\mathchardef\lambda="0415
\mathchardef\mu="0416
\mathchardef\nu="0417
\mathchardef\xi="0418
\mathchardef\pi="0419
\mathchardef\rho="041A
\mathchardef\sigma="041B
\mathchardef\tau="041C
\mathchardef\upsilon="041D
\mathchardef\phi="041E
\mathchardef\chi="041F
\mathchardef\psi="0420
\mathchardef\omega="0421
\mathchardef\varepsilon="0422
\mathchardef\vartheta="0423
\mathchardef\varpi="0424
\mathchardef\varrho="0425
\mathchardef\varsigma="0426
\mathchardef\varphi="0427
\mathchardef\imath="047B
\mathchardef\jmath="047C
\mathchardef\ell="0460
\mathchardef\wp="047D
\mathchardef\partial="0440
\mathchardef\flat="045B
\mathchardef\natural="045C
\mathchardef\sharp="045D
\mathchardef\triangleleft="242F
\mathchardef\triangleright="252E
\mathchardef\star="243F

\mathchardef\smile="345E
\mathchardef\frown="345F
\mathchardef\leftharpoonup="3428
\mathchardef\leftharpoondown="3429
\mathchardef\rightharpoonup="342A
\mathchardef\rightharpoondown="342B

\mathchardef\lhook="342C \def\hookrightarrow{\lhook\joinrel\rightarrow}
\mathchardef\rhook="342D \def\hookleftarrow{\leftarrow\joinrel\rhook}


\mathchardef\<"343C
\mathchardef\>"343E
\mathchardef\slash"043D
\mathchardef\."643A
\mathchardef\,"643B


\mathcode`\<="343C
\mathcode`\>="343E
\mathcode`\/="043D
\mathcode`\.="643A
\mathcode`\,="643B
```

But whenever I invoke it, a strange thing happens with my matrices.  Consider the following code:

```
\input mathchar
$$\matrix{a&b\cr c&d\cr}$$
\bye
```

This produces the following output:

[image]

I'm not sure whether those are periods and commas, or semicolons, or something else.  With larger matrices I tend to get just commas (or maybe they're single quotes) with no periods.

I would love to know which line in `mathchar.tex` is causing this.

Comment: `\matrix` is defined to insert a small space on either side of it via `\,`. Your `mathchar.tex` redefines `\,` to be something other than a small space: `"643B` represents a punctuation `;` of family 4 (taken from section **38.3.1 Mathcharacter codes** in [TeX by Topic](//texdoc.net/pkg/texbytopic)).

Comment: @Werner:  That absolutely solves my problem.  If you post it as an answer I'll accept it.  Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

There is a big difference between

```
\mathchardef\."643A
```

and

```
\mathcode`\.="643A
```

With the latter you're saying that the character `.`, when found in math mode, should produce a punctuation atom (`6`) taken from math font family `4`, slot `"3A`.

The former *defines* the control sequence `\.` to produce the same math atom described above.

In the latter, `\.` ***doesn't*** stand for a control sequence, because it is preceded by a back quote in a context where TeX is expecting a number and the whole

```
`\.
```

denotes an alphabetical constant (the ASCII code of the period). Using

```
\mathcode`.="643A
```

would do exactly the same. By rule, when an alphabetical constant is involved, the character can be escaped (in some case it must be, for instance `%`), without changing the meaning in any way. The resulting control sequence is not even added to the hash table.

With your code

```
\mathchardef\<"343C
\mathchardef\>"343E
\mathchardef\."643A
\mathchardef\,"643B
```

you are defining `\<` and *redefining* `\>`, `\.` and `\,`. You clearly don't want it. Your problem is indeed in the redefinition of `\,`, because `\matrix` uses it:

```
\def\matrix#1{\null\,\vcenter{\normalbaselines\m@th
    \ialign{\hfil$##$\hfil&&\quad\hfil$##$\hfil\crcr
      \mathstrut\crcr\noalign{\kern-\baselineskip}
      #1\crcr\mathstrut\crcr\noalign{\kern-\baselineskip}}}\,}
```

By the way, your assignment `` \mathcode`\, `` seems rather dubious, as you get a semicolon, not a comma.